# Bootstrap creating extra padding on column in row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let me preface this by saying I am relatively new to bootstrap and possibly not udnerstanding the row/column layouts properly.

The layout I am working on can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/5NFXY/ (code pasted below)

The 'sidebar' on the right is where the problem is occurring. I have a `.col-md-9` and a `.col-md-3` enclosed withing a `.row`, but for some reason the right side of the sidebar is not lining up properly with its container. After playing around with this for quite some time I have found that if I remove `margin-right: -15px;` from the `.row` the problem goes away, but surely this isn't' the proper solution and I have mucked something up along the way. My question is, have I done something wrong in my HTML or is the proper solution really to manually override that `margin-right: -15px;`?

---

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <h4>Subheader</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-container clearfix">
            <!-- Static navbar -->
            <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Operations <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Get Started</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Start New</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header"> Settings</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Manage Types</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Manage Types</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Utilities <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Distance</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Administration <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="">News</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Alts <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="wrath-content-box news-post">
                        <h1>Title Bar</h1>
                        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrath-content-box news-post">
                        <h1>Title Bar</h1>
                        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrath-content-box news-post">
                        <h1>Title Bar</h1>
                        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrath-content-box news-post">
                        <h1>Title Bar</h1>
                        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 wrath-content-box">
                    <h1>Title Bar</h1>
                    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="wrath-content-box">
                Footer tagline &copy;
            </footer>
        </div> <!-- /inner-container -->
    </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: url('../img/wh-background-1.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.logo-header {
    color: #FFF;
}
.logo-header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.logo-header h4 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
footer {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.inner-container {
    background: rgba(119, 119, 119, .5);
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.wrath-content-box {
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.news-post {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Using: Bootstrap 3.0.3 + Jquery 1.10.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've combined your custom class `wrath-content-box` with the bootstrap `col-md-3` class and the padding on your class is overriding the Bootsrap grid padding.

You just need to put your class in a separate `<div>` inside the bootstrap one like you did in the first column.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="wrath-content-box">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/5NFXY/2/)**

Comment: Correct you are, thank you! I tried removing the padding from .wrath-content-box as a test because I had the same thought but that didn't fix it. However when I moved it into its own div as you have shown that corrected it.

Comment: Yeah I personally try to keep the Bootstrap grid classes on their own, tends to make code a bit clearer.